# Grab one row from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, left-join, outer-join

I have a view and a table that I'm trying to get data out of. My view has basic order information based on an order number. The table I'm getting data out of has very detailed pieces of data based on an order number. When I run the view by itself, I get basic order header information. When I query the table, I get bill of material level details. I only need one column of data from the table, to be added to the result set of the view. I currently have:

```
SELECT
    x.ORDER_NUMBER, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    Quantity, 
    x.ORDER_NUMBER + '-' + y.Shipment AS [Ship_Set]
FROM 
    vw_OrderData AS x
JOIN
    DetailData AS y ON (x.ORDER_NUMBER = y.ORDER_NUMBER)
```

I'm trying to get the result set from `vw_OrderData`, then grab and concatenate the `Shipment` number from the `DetailData` table, as that column doesn't exist in the `vw_OrderData`.

What I'm getting is every row from the `DetailData` table that has a matching `ORDER_NUMBER`. I'm fairly certain I'm not joining correctly, but I'm still learning SQL. Appreciated.

Comment: We need to know what database engine you are using. The answer will vary based on that.

Comment: I'm running this on SQL2012

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Comment: I think the problem is that he has more than one row in the table for the same order_number and thus getting more than one result in the view where he expects to only get a single record

Comment: Just a minor tip regarding table aliases, I'd have o as in orderdata, and d as in detaildata. Easier to remember than x and y, better when writing the query, and for others reading your code.

Comment: It results in returning all rows for the ORDER_NUMBER in both the view and the table, resulting in too many rows due to the granularity of the table.

Comment: Mark, is there just one Shipment number for each ORDER_NUMBER?

Comment: ednincer, there can be multiple shipment numbers per order number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted the following:

```
SELECT o.ORDER_NUMBER, Description, Price, Quantity, 
   o.ORDER_NUMBER + '-' + COALESCE(dd.Shippment, '') AS [Ship_Set]
FROM vw_OrderData o LEFT JOIN
   DetailData dd
ON o.ORDER_NUMBER = dd.ORDER_NUMBER;
```

It returned the same amount of rows because there were multiple line items per order number. I did not try the TOP 1 solution, but rather went back into my OrderData view, and saw that it was already pulling from the DetailData table for a couple other rows, so I simply added:

```
DetailData.OrderNumber+'-'+COALESCE(DetailData.Shippment,'00') as [Ship_Set]
```

as a column to the result set of the view, then just added the column to the original select statement in question without having to do the join:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_NUMBER, 
    Description, 
    Price, 
    Quantity, 
    [Ship_Set]
FROM 
    vw_OrderData
```

Answer (score 1):

If it gives you multiple rows, but only need the first one, you could use the `SELECT TOP(1)` option such as :

```
SELECT TOP(1)
x.ORDER_NUMBER, 
Description, 
Price, 
Quantity, 
x.ORDER_NUMBER+'-'+y.Shippment AS [Ship_Set]
FROM vw_OrderData AS x
join DetailData AS y
ON(x.ORDER_NUMBER = y.ORDER_NUMBER)
```

Therefore your query works exactly as depicted. You should probably instead refine it, what do you exactly need ? why every row from the DetailData table that has a matching ORDER_NUMBER is too much ? do you need more specific results ?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is a `LEFT JOIN` (because you want to keep all the rows in the first table).

```
SELECT o.ORDER_NUMBER, Description, Price, Quantity, 
       o.ORDER_NUMBER + '-' + COALESCE(dd.Shippment, '') AS [Ship_Set]
FROM vw_OrderData o LEFT JOIN
     DetailData dd
     ON o.ORDER_NUMBER = dd.ORDER_NUMBER;
```

Notice the `COALESCE()`.  Without the `COALESCE()`, `Ship_Set` would be `NULL` for non-matching records.  That might be desirable.  With it, you get the order number with a hyphen and nothing after the hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to grab 1 row, then you want

```
SELECT top 1
x.ORDER_NUMBER, ...
```

Note that this assumes that *any* y.Shippment entry will do, which may not be the case in your data.